# Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object. Then i create package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try to create package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CARS AS
  TYPE REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  TYPE car_arr IS TABLE OF my_cars%ROWTYPE;
  PROCEDURE getAllCars(cars OUT REFCURSOR);
  FUNCTION getCarById(id IN VARCHAR2) RETURN REFCURSOR;
END CARS;
```

I get: Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Check if the object named 'CARS' exists in the current users schema: SELECT owner, object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE object_name = 'CARS';

Comment: Error message is pretty clear

Comment: @Mighty.Moogle OWNER: my user, OBJECT_NAME: CARS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object names are unique within a schema. If we have (say) a table called `"CARS"` we cannot also have a package called `"CARS"`.

> Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object.

So clearly you have already created an object called `"CARS"`. If you have forgotten what that object is, run

```
 select * from user_objects
 where object_name = 'CARS';
```

The `object_type` column will tell you what kind of object you already have with that name. You have three choices:

1. give the package a different name
2. drop the existing object
3. rename the existing object

The first option seems easier but YMMV.